# Is there a way to define android drawable containing a stack of images, using just xml?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to use a set of 2 image layers as a background in my Layout XML.

I am guessing I can do it :

1. Using code, may be by extending the ImageView/Canvas/Drawable, which is I am trying avoiding.
2. Using Layout XML, with 2 nested Layouts with each layer image as a background. OR a FrameLayout with 2 ImageViews in it.

But, I was wondering if there is another way to define a drawable using XML (just like I define an Animation Set using XML).

Something like this :

### mylayout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/2_image_layer_drawable" >
```

### 2_image_layer_drawable.xml [imaginary]

```
   <Set>
       <drawable src="@image_layer_back"/>
       <drawable src="@image_layer_front"/>
   </Set>
```

Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`layer-list`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) with two [`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)(with those images) drawables as children.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Awesome! layer-list was exactly what I was looking for. I had a feeling something like this was available, but couldn't find it.

Thanks @Luksprog!

Comment: @dostiharise I've also added a small example with a `layer-list`.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could Vote up the Answer, but not enough reputation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this:

Save the below code with `.xml` file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@image_layer_back" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@image_layer_back" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@image_layer_back" />
    <item android:drawable="@image_layer_front" />
</selector>
```

Comment: No, I have used selectors before for buttons. I think layer-list is what I am looking for. :-)

Thanks @VineetShukla